# How to move an div element up using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var selectd = 0;
  var itemLv1 = $("#create-summary .lv1"); 
  $(itemLv1).click(function(){
    selected = $(this).index(".lv1");
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
  });

  $("#moveUp").click(function(){
    if(selected > 0){
      jQuery($(itemLv1).eq(selected - 1).before(jQuery($(itemLv1).eq(selected))));
      selected = selected - 1;
      console.log(selected);
    }
  });
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color:red;
}

.lv2 {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="create-summary">
            <div class="lv1">1. AAA</div>
            <div class="lv1">2. BBB</div>
            <div class="lv1">3. CCC</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.1 111</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.2 222</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.3 333</div>
            <div class="lv1">4. DDD</div>
            <div class="lv1">5. EEE</div>
          </div>

<button type="button" id="moveUp">Up </button>
```

Now, I write some jQuery to move my div up and it works but only move one time.
The div will not move correctly when click up again.

What is the problem?

Also, How to move  "lv1" class with "lv2" class at the same time?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/pwhnjutg/. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Sushil you had a few errors, here is a fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwhnjutg/1/

Comment: @Jezzabeanz there were no errors in my fiddle. you just took my fiddle and added replaced `current` with `$(current)`. if you see carefully current is already a jquery object so you don't have to go and add a `$` again.

Comment: Run your fiddle and look in the console. Also why are you getting so defensive? I'm just trying to help.

Comment: To all those answering, there are two linked questions here; the first: "*what is the problem?*" and the second "*How to move 'lv1' class with 'lv2' class at the same time?*" Please try not to avoid the first question.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz, I looked in the console for Sushil's code and no errors were noted by Chrome. Also, both versions of that script ignore the second part of the question (as noted in my previous question).

Comment: I checked the console before replying to you. I am not getting defensive. what you've done doesn't make any sense. adding a `$` to an object that is already a jquery object doesn't make any sense. correcting a spelling mistake is no error.

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right. my bad I missed the second part of the question. it seems Stryner has already fixed that in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to store the element instead of the index:

```
// Store Element here instead of Index
var $selectd = $();
var $itemLv1 = $("#create-summary .lv1"); 
$itemLv1.click(function(){
    $selectd = $(this); //Note: Storing element instead of index
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});

$("#moveUp").click(function(){
    // Take the current selected element (if none, jQuery doesn't do anything)
    $selectd.add($selectd.nextUntil(":not(.lv2)"))        // Add any following `.lv2` elements to the collection
            .insertBefore($selectd.prevAll(".lv1:first")) // Insert before the previous `.lv1`
});
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knexpvqn/

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to move the element up:

```
$("#moveUp").click(function () {
    $(".clicked").insertBefore($("#create-summary").children().get($(".clicked").index() - 1));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/05ngx8c4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pen: http://codepen.io/nOji/pen/RPvexe

The issue that I noticed with your code is that `itemLv1` variable won't be the representation of your elements after DOM manipulation, therefore the click event on inserted elements won't work and moving up action will not query the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#create-summary .lv1").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});

$("#moveUp").click(function () {
    var selected = $("#create-summary").find(".clicked");
    selected.prev().before( selected );
});
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color:red;
}
.lv2 {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="create-summary">
    <div class="lv1">1. AAA</div>
    <div class="lv1">2. BBB</div>
    <div class="lv1">3. CCC</div>
    <div class="lv2">3.1 111</div>
    <div class="lv2">3.2 222</div>
    <div class="lv2">3.3 333</div>
    <div class="lv1">4. DDD</div>
    <div class="lv1">5. EEE</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="moveUp">Up</button>
```